# How to move to another part of the code using an if statement

Tags: objective-c

in my code I have the following if statement:

```
if (a.count >= 2) {
    t2 = array[b % a.count];
    array[0] = t2;
}
```

I have another if statement that goes like the first. What I want it to do is if a <= 0 then goto a certain line, or skip over certain parts of code. How would I do this? I was thinking something along the lines of

```
 if (a.count <= 0) {
    goto line 96 
 }
```

This wouldn't work, the syntax is wrong, but how would I do this?

Comment: this looks like an XY problem. You probably want to refactor your code so that you don't need to jump around like that. If you have one condition, then put its consequences in one block.

Answer (score 1):

Goto statements are generally considered bad programming and excessive utilization of them can lead to code that is hard to maintain and debug.

That said, if/else/else if provide all the functionality you need.

I recommend putting the code you need to run inside that if statement in a separate method and then calling it from the if statement.

```
if (a.count <= 0) {
    nameOfNewMethod();
}

//somewhere else
- (void) nameOfNewMethod {
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the lines of code you want to "goto" in a function (or if appropriate, a block) and call the function (or block).  If there are lines of code you want to skip, you can always return early out of a function, or use an `else` block?

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact a `goto` command in Objective-C. To utilize it, you have to create a label, ex:

```
marker:
```

and jump to it like so within the same method:

```
goto marker;
```

But you can't declare any variables between those two commands. All the variables have to be created before the jump so that they still exist after.

Here's an example of how to use `goto`:

```
    int x = 0;

    if (a.count <= 0) {
        goto marker; 
    }

    x = 5;

marker:; // <-- semi-colon indicates the label is followed by an empty statement, thus allowing for immediate variable declaration

    int y = x + 7;
```

In that case, if a.count <= 0, y == 7, else y == 12.

Comment: While this technically works, changing the architecture of the code will probably create a more readable and maintainable code base.

Comment: @Logan Just answering the question.

Comment: Fair enough, just thought a disclaimer might help the weary beginner who stumbles this way.  :)